# What does usp_parmsel stand for?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm learning about SQL databases so that I can work on an existing database, and I noticed this naming convention used on a lot of the files.

I'm thinking usp stands for User Stored Procedures, but I'm not entirely certain what parmsel is for. I've tried looking this up and see others using it with the case `parmSel`...

So what does usp_parmsel stand for?

The files are named like so under Programmability > Stored Procedures in the SQL Object Explorer:

```
dbo.usp_parmsel_CustomerExists
dbo.usp_parmsel_CustomerReferral
dbo.usp_parmsel_CustomerReceipt
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is a wellknown convention. At first glance it looks like abbreviated *parameterSelect*.

Comment: You'll have to ask whoever is responsible for/designed that database.

Comment: Yes you have got the first bit right usp stands for User-defined Stored Procedures , the second bit of the name should suggest what this stored procedure does, if the names doesnt make much sense just use `EXECUTE sp_helptext usp_parmsel`, this will return the procedure definition.

Comment: Yeah, when I googled it I didn't get many results back, but I -did- see other people using it, unfortunately what they were using it for went over my head so not helpful.

It's like usp_parmsel_NameofWhatProcedureDoes1
usp_parmsel_NameofWhatProcedureDoes2, usp_parmsel_NameofWhatProcedureDoes3, etc... so it's not for explaining what the procedure does...

If it's that uncommon I'll just ask them about it, just didn't want to ask something if it's some kind of common naming convention I didn't know about.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, guys. I think it's referring to `parameter select` in this particular instance, since I think these are for gathering user data for the parameters for some code in Visual Studio.

Comment: There is very large and vague information about "parmsel" en ligne take a look here it may help http://www.vbi.org/Books/Samples/Wrox/BeginningSQL2k/46721504.htm

Comment: he's asking about a local naming convention -- it's not something the community would be interested in.

Comment: I don't think it's a popular naming convention, but I -did- see instances of it being used on other websites with older programs, so it's not entirely local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to verify 100% with a higher up-- it stands for Parameter Select.

I saw a few places online where this was used, it looks like a rather old naming convention-- which makes sense, I'm working with an old system.

Answer (score 0):

Parmsel stands for parameter selector. You can look up parameter selectors on an engine search machine.
Apparently The PARMSEL field determines the format of the remainder of the area.
There is very vague information about it online.

Maybe this? https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CodeRush/CustomDocument1524

Comment: That's one wild assumption you are making here, friend.

Comment: I'm guessing you got the initial idea for it determining the format of the remainder of the area from this documentation for Nortel, as it's one of the first of few relevant results from Google. Unfortunately, I think that's only relevant to their system. Thanks though. http://willowcherry.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/411-2831-455.14.06.pdf